# Least squares estimator of normally distributed observations

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, blue

I am trying to comprehend what the authors are asking me to show in this following exercise problem from Hogg, McKean and Craig's book titled "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics."

**3.5.22.** Readers may have encountered the multiple regression model in a previous course in statistics. We can briefly write it as follows. Suppose we have a vector of $n$ observations $Y$ which has the distribution $N_n(X\beta, \sigma^2I)$, where $X$ is an $n \times p$ matrix of known values, which has full column rank $p$, and $\beta$ is a $p \times 1$ vector of unknown parameters. The least squares estimator of $\beta$ is
$$\hat{\beta} = (X′X)^{−1}X′Y.$$
(a) Determine the distribution of $\hat{\beta}$.

(b) Let $\hat{Y} = X\hat{\beta}$. Determine the distribution of $\hat{Y}$ .

(c) Let $\hat{e} = Y − \hat{Y}$ . Determine the distribution of $\hat{e}$.

(d) By writing the random vector $(\hat{Y}′,\hat{e}′)′$ as a linear function of Y, show that the random vectors $\hat{Y}$ and $\hat{e}$ are independent.

(e) Show that $\hat{\beta}$ solves the least squares problem; that is, \begin{equation}\Vert Y − X \hat{\beta} \Vert ^2 = \min_{b \in R^p} \Vert Y − X b \Vert ^2.\end{equation}

**My question:** While parts (a) through (d) are trivial (and part (e) might as well be), I am not able to understand what the author wants me to show?

Given a vector of observations/responses $Y$, with the matrix of predictors being $X$, if $b$ is the least squares estimator, then show that it minimizes $\Vert Y − X b \Vert ^2$ is the question.

In linear algebra, the best predictor of $Y$ given $X$ is basically the projection of $Y$ onto the range of $X$. The norm is the usual distance norm, and is dealt with in standard linear algebra textbooks.

However, in this question, the *distribution* of $Y$ is given and the author is asking us to show that the least squares estimator solves the minimization problem. So how is the norm defined in this context? Is the author expecting us to show that the variance of the residual is minimum when the estimator is that of least squares similar to what was done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1543380/145325)?

Please help me comprehend what the authors are expecting me to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exercise is straightforward. There are no hidden intricacies here. You know $\mathbf Y\sim \mathrm N(\mathbf X\boldsymbol \beta, \sigma^2\mathbf I) .$ Using this, you need to find the distributions of $\hat{\mathbf Y}$ and this is nothing but $\mathbf M\mathbf Y$ where $\bf M$ is the projection operator on $\mathcal C(\mathbf X). $ The other questions are similar. Finally, as of $\rm (e) ,$ you guessed it right: you need to show $\hat{\boldsymbol \beta}$ is indeed the least square estimator if it satisfies the given minimization relation. And this only happens if and only if $\mathbf X\hat{\boldsymbol \beta}=\mathbf M\mathbf Y. $ As Ronald Christensen asserted, least squares estimation is not a "statistical procedure": you don't need to assume any distribution. Yes, in OLS, the MLE estimators coincide with $\hat{\boldsymbol \beta}$ but the minimization problem doesn't need any additional distribution assumption and the authors didn't even say so (otherwise they would have framed the question like *hence, show that...*).

Comment: Thanks for the information. The only reason I asked is because I could not figure out the motivation for asking a question that was perhaps more suitable for a course in Linear Algebra (how do you minimize $Y-Xb$ given vector $Y$ and matrix $X$), that too when they specified that $Y$ has normal distribution. I wanted to make sure that part (e) did not translate to "Prove Gauss-Markov theorem" ... makes sense as there is no reference to the estimator being BLUE or what not.

Comment: Yes. You don't need to resort to Gauss-Markov for deducing the minimization relation.